# How to properly catch, wrap and re-throw a Hibernate exceptions?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

My database worker is implemented above the Hibernate. If something goes wrong, it's methods should rollback the transaction and throw an `SQLException`. So my question is: what is the best (i.e. cleanest) way to handle Hibernate exceptions? Currently all my methods looks as ugly as this:

```
public EntryUserHib addUser(final String username, final String pwdhash) throws SQLException{
    try {
        final Transaction ta = sess.beginTransaction();
        try {
            // Using Hibernate here
            // "return" statement
        } catch(final HibernateException ex) {
            try {
                ta.rollback();
            } catch(final Exception ex1) {}
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (!ta.wasRolledBack()) ta.commit();
        }
    } catch(final HibernateException ex) {
        if (ex.getCause() != null) {
            if (ex.getCause() instanceof SQLException) throw (SQLException)ex.getCause();
            throw new SQLException(ex.getCause());
        }
        throw new SQLException(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let someone else manage it for you, like Spring. It has [extensive Hibernate and transaction support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) that will extract all of that code that you're worried about.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look toward it, but do I really need to use a framework just for a single class exception management?

Comment: It's a common misconception that Spring is "only" a framework. It has tons of reusable libraries packed into it. For example, for your situation, it offers a [TransactionTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) and a [HibernateTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html) (as linked previously) that do exactly what you're asking. Yes you could write them yourself, but why?

Answer (score 3):

Don't catch them at all. Hibernate exceptions extend RuntimeException for two good reasons: you don't have to declare them in method signatures, and any RuntimeException automatically causes a rollback of the transaction. Exception-handling makes for very cluttered code. The Hibernate folks have the philosophy that HibernateExceptions should be fatal errors, signaling coding or logic errors, and in a properly-function application should not be (and doesn't need to be) caught.

Your application's UI should respond to these surprises in a user-friendly way, though. That's a separate issue.

Comment: This is a server application with no UI and many parallel tasks running, and none of those should ever harm the whole application, so I really need to catch them and re-throw in a declared way. Another reason for this is the fact, that there are three implementations of my `DatabaseWorker` - using Hibernate, JDBC and simple in-memory model for tests, and currently i can freely switch them.

Comment: HibernateException wrapps a bunch of other exception inc SQLException, this can be a network glitch, not necessarily coding or logic, may or may not be fatal depending on your app. In a server situation there is usually nothing "fatal" about a HibernateException, it should usually be caught and delt with and the server should continue.